# Sum : $\sum_{t=1}^{r} t\binom{n-t}{n-r}=\binom{n+1}{r-1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

We want to prove that:

> $$\sum_{t=1}^{r} t\binom{n-t}{n-r}=\binom{n+1}{r-1}$$

I have used basic properties of binomial coefficients like $$\binom{n+1}{r+1}= \frac{n+1}{r+1}\binom{n}{r}$$ but they seems to be of no use.

I have managed to prove that :

$$\sum_{t=0}^{n}\binom{r+t}{r}=\binom{r+n+1}{r+1}$$

The two series are similar in the sense that the lower number of binomial coefficient in both is a  constant. However , I can't get rid of the variable multiplication of $t$ to the binomial coefficient in the first series. How can I proceed further or are there other methods to solve it ?

Comment: Check this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2374765/42969